# MQTT subscription issue: The length of my received packet is always 19 characters

Tags: teensy, mqtt

This is my first post here so bear with me if I accidentally didn't follow conventional standards here. Here's the issue:

I am using a teensy 3.2 and WINC1500 wifi breakout to play around with MQTT protocols. I am currently using the AdaFruit MQTT library, found https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_MQTT_Library, and I have configured my WIFI chip to successfully send and receive packets which I am able to see through MQTT.FX, a client data broker. The issue I have is regarding the subscribe function. When I receive a packet, I want to parse the information however, I only get back the message up to 19 characters. I assume this is some variable in the library that has been set. I unfortunately have searched and found the variable name, `SUBSCRIPTIONDATALEN` and increased it to hold more data. However, it doesn't change anything. Is there a hardware limitation to the size of a packet received? Or is the size of the message you send limited to the amount of memory you have available? Is there anyway I can increase it to encapsulate the whole message?

The string I want to parse is : `{"target":"Lamp", "code":"lamp", "values": { "lampon":0, "brightness":100,"luminosity": 122}}`

What I received back is : `{"target":"Lamp", "c`

Any suggestions would be very appreciated! Also would this topic matter fit better in the CS site or is it appropriate to be posted in this forum? Thank you very much!

Comment: Code example? It would be better, please use the code formatting button when posting. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for responding! I was actually able to find the source of the issue. I had downloaded two identical versions of the library by accident. Installed one, while making changes in the other. When I tried to read back my packets, I was always limited to the default values even though I had thought I changed them. I removed both libraries, reinstalled them, and changed the max length. Thanks for the advice regarding code formatting. I am very new to this forum and didn't know that.